# Using R shiny with an external javascript file for event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

I'm trying to create a R Shiny app in which an external javascript is included. As a newbie, this javascript should for now only detect the press of enter and simulate the click of that button.
The Shiny interface looks like this where text is being inputted and when the Send-button is clicked that same text outputted:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  includeScript("sendOnEnter.js"),

  titlePanel("GUI"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("text",h3("Cmd"),value="Enter question"),
      actionButton("send", "Send"),
      width = 3
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("query")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  ntext <- eventReactive(input$send, {
            input$text
              })

  output$query <- renderText({ 
    ntext()

    })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The Javascript file listens for the pressing of the enter button and simulates this as the clicking of the Send button;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#entry').keypress(function(evt){

    if (evt.keyCode == 13){
      // Enter, simulate clicking send
      jQuery('#send').click();
    }
  });
})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, there was a typo in script. `jQuery('#entry').keypress(...)`should be `jQuery('#text').keypress(..)`

Comment: I think this code works without the JavaScript file.